# Jquery validation: Error message always displayed more than once

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to validate using jquery validation and the error messages displayed it in a div container. My problem is when i typed something to my input fields error message always appear in "div.info" but i just want error messages always appear when i submit a form. And my next problem is when i submit more than once error messages also display more than once too?

My code is like below

Html code

```
<div class="info"></div>
 <form id="fmlogin">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){       
        $("form#fmlogin").submit(function() {
            data= $("form#fmlogin").serialize();
            return false;
        });

        $("#fmlogin").validate({
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email:true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                }
            },      
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Email Address is required",
                email:"Email Address is not Valid"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Password is required",
            }
          },
        errorElement: "div",
        wrapper: "div", 
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {  
            error.appendTo($('.info'));
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){          
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data:data,
                success: function(response){
                    $(".info").text(response);
                }   
            }); 
        }
        }); 
        });
</script>
```

I am new with jquery validation, please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fmlogin

use this

```
  var data=$("#fmlogin").serialize();
 $("#fmlogin").submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data:data,
            success: function(response){
      //if you want to show error more that once than use append instead of text
                $(".info").append(response);
            }   
    })
```

Comment: thx for reply, my problem is with jquery validation not with ajax. i want error messages appear when i submit a form not when i type something to my input fields and next problem is when i try to submit more than once error message always appear in my div.info more than once too.

Comment: @casper that's the solution i have posted? Use the submit event after `validation` so that it will be called once.And use `append ` so show error multiple time as you post the data.